# Google +1 integration?

Tags: feature-request

Would that be feasible to integrate Google +1 to StackExchange sites?

**UPDATE**:

I'm sorry if the request is not clear enough. Google +1 will later provide button that can be put in any webpage so people can +1 page they like and refer it to their friends and other people.

I think it would be nice if StackExchange can modify its upvote for the questions to automatically also sent +1 information to Google. This means a page with high upvote would be better shown in Google search.

An alternative of course is to have another +1 button in the question page. The downside is people that upvote the question will need to +1 the question if they want to.

Would it be feasible?

Comment: How so[?](http://www.google.com/)

Comment: what @waiwai933 is asking is "how could this be implemented and how would it make things better?

Comment: I don't think Google will allow programmatic submissions to +1.

Comment: @Pekka, I think if there is a way to track the 'clicker's Google account', it would be feasible. And remember, one has to have Google Profiles filled to be allowed to use +1

Comment: [google-1-integration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85417/google-1-integration)?

Comment: Right now when I find a useful answer I manually go back and +1 it on the search result page where I found it so that others can skip over the less useful pages. Having that option right here on the page would be immensely helpful. It wouldn't need to display the number of +1s either, if not showing prevents conflict with the built in vote system.

Comment: Although this is an old question, I thought I'd share my idea: the +1 button can be set to `opacity:0` and placed on top of the vote up arrow. So voting up a question +1s it, and voting it down does nothing else (-1s aren't possible). Then the `data-url` attribute could be used to +1 answers. However, users not logged into Google will get a popup asking them to log in, which might confuse them. This will help get the good questions higher up in Google searches.