# Google +1 support

Tags: feature-request, social-networking, sharing, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any plans supporting Google+ for link sharing in the near future?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future)

I've seen [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85417/google-1-integration) similar question but for whatever reason it's dead and old.

Anyway, now that Google+ is practically in an almost-open beta and +1 buttons have started appearing on quite a few websites, how about we add +1 buttons to the Stack Exchange family along with the other social sharing buttons

Comment: I'd rather have fewer than more. Then again, I may be anti-social...

Comment: I have a friend that's never signed up for any social networks and even he bought into Google+

Comment: We already have +1 buttons that work just fine for me. Why do we need Google's as well?

Comment: @Cody I was waiting for that. I'm also waiting for "did Google steal our voting button idea" questions

Comment: This seems like a good idea. After all, we're already encouraged to share questions and answers, might as well have more ways to easily do so.

Comment: @Anna especially because at the moment most of the google+ users are more technical

Comment: -1, When Google+ drops requiring public profiles, I'll consider this proposal.

Comment: @six facebook and myspace doesn't?

Comment: @Earlz: neither of them were my email provider with which I had a private profile until they decided to become a (poor) social network.

Comment: @six ah well having a +1 button there isn't exactly auto opt-in :)